# Basic custom Shortcode not working

Tags: shortcode

This is the simple version of what im trying to accomplish

```
//add display_name shortcode
function name_shortcode( ){
    return "testshortcode";
}
function register_shortcodes(){
    add_shortcode('display-name', 'name_shortcode');
}
add_action( 'init', 'register_shortcodes');
```

Which isnt working, the short code gets added to a custom post type called email. Grab the content using

```
$email_body = get_the_content();
```

And then email it out. But on the email body, i still only see the [display-name] short code text, instead of the quick "testshortcode" i set up.

Eventually if i get this to work, i would like this actually grab the the actual users display name from a wp_user_query loop i have set up in a seperate chron job funtion to send out a list of reminder emails... but one step at a time.

Comment: You can use `do_shortcode` for your content.

Comment: How would that work? do_shortcode($email_body)?

Answer (score 1):

`get_the_content` returns the content as is without processing, it does not pass it through the filters that are used in `the_content` such as oembeds or shortcodes. This filter is also called `the_content` ( coincidence )

Instead use this:

```
$email_body = apply_filters( 'the_content', get_the_content() );
```

Comment: I just tested it out, didnt work for me

Comment: the email body also now has all the html being displayed, span tags and what not.... that wasnt showing up before, and the shortcode is still not being translated

Comment: Are you waiting for the init hook to fire before sending the email? More context will be necessary, and it's likely the issue I solved above and the issue you're having now are not the same, although the result is